# Flexbox: выравнивание по центру обрезает контент на маленьких экранах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Есть модальное окно (display: flex), содержимое которого выровнено по центру экрана (justify-content: center; align-items: center). На больших экранах всё смотрится и работает как надо. Но на мобильных устройствах, высота которых меньше содержимого, контент обрезается сверху и снизу. В частности, недоступна кнопка "закрыть окно".

**1.** Почему не появляется полоса прокрутки? Чем объясняется такое поведение flexbox?

**2.** Можно ли в рамках flex решить эту проблему? Или придётся выравнивать содержимое иначе, без использования flex?

```js
$('.open-btn').click(function(){
  $('.modal-window').css('display','flex');
})
$('.close-btn').click(function(){
  $('.modal-window').css('display','none');
})
```

```css
.modal-window {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1cacf3;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal-content {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.modal-content .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open-btn">Открыть окно</button>
<div class="modal-window">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <p class="close-btn">Закрыть</p>
      <h1>Заголовок модального окна</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выравнивайте не через `justify-content` и `align-items`, а `margin: auto` для `.modal-content`. Ну и `overflow: auto` для `.modal-window`

```js
$('.open-btn').click(function(){
  $('.modal-window').css('display','flex');
})
$('.close-btn').click(function(){
  $('.modal-window').css('display','none');
})
```

```css
.modal-window {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1cacf3;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal-content {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
.modal-content .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open-btn">Открыть окно</button>
<div class="modal-window">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <p class="close-btn">Закрыть</p>
      <h1>Заголовок модального окна</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас :)

Comment: @zhurof Хороший, добротный ответ (+) Всё чётко и ясно

Answer (score 1):

Да, вам правильно посоветовали выравнивать через margin: auto;. Для устранения бага в IE, когда окно растягивается по высоте, используйте для модального окна align-self: center;

Answer (score -1):

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  .modal-content {
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

Попробуйте к вашему коду добавить медиа-запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а Вы сами попробовали, прежде чем давать ответ? :)

Comment: @humster_spb, добавил скрин. Текст же удлиняется, или надо именно полосу прокрутки?

Comment: Ну, Вы мой пример воспроизвели? Увидели, в чём там проблема? Если Ваш ответ работает, сделайте такой же воспроизводимый сниппет. Я попробовал добавить - у меня ничего не произошло. max-width: 200px тут вообще не при чём - обрезается по высоте (тогда уж max-height)